# CKEditor nested paragraphs issue inside custom block style div not displaying properly

Tags: css, html, ckeditor

in the custom styles inside CKEditor, I have created a "Tip" block element that I want to have  span one or more paragraphs.  However, when I am editing my text (using the inline editor), I am unable to get the block style to work across multiple paragraphs.

My style looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('authorStyles', [
// Block-level styles
{
    name: 'Yellow Tip',
    element: 'p',
    styles: {
        margin: '1em 0',
        padding: '20px 20px 4px',
        border: '1px solid',
        'border-radius': '15px',
        'background-color': '#FFC',
        'border-color': '#CC9'
    }
}
]);
```

In the config.js, I added the line to wire-up the custom style

```
// custom styles
config.stylesSet = 'authorStyles:../authorStyle.js';
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="section right" contenteditable="true" id="contentToSubmit">
        <p>Here we have some addtional content that is also editable as well in addition to being just some text on its own right.</p>
        <p>Here we have some addtional content that is also editable as well in addition to being just some text on its own right.</p>
        <p>Here we have some addtional content that is also editable as well in addition to being just some text on its own right.</p>
        <p>Here we have some addtional content that is also editable as well in addition to being just some text on its own right.</p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, when I select two paragraphs to be contained in my div, they both display as their own blocks, instead of both `<p>` tags being inside my custom `<div>`.

[Paragraphs not displaying properly inside custom block style div](http://www.jasonlindsay.com/files/ckeditor_nested_div_p_problem_example.jpg)

I tried resetting the default enter key behavior (via the enterkey extra plugin), but the only thing I could get to work is setting the enter key behavior to line break (`<br/>`) which isn't desirable.

I have looked around for help on this particular issue, but can't seem to find an article that deals with this problem.  Can anyone help me?  We are trying to determine whether ckeditor will be sufficient for our needs, but this is a big blocking issue for our content editors.

Comment: I don't know what do you want to achieve. Could you describe **shortly** what's an expected behaviour and what's the actual one?

Comment: I edited your question and found there unescaped HTML tags. Now the question is a little bit more clear.

Comment: @Reinmar, basically I want to have a div with the custom style that contains the p's inside of it.  When I select multiple paragraphs and apply the custom style, the style is applied to each paragraph individually instead of wrapping the p's inside an outer div.Thanks for the edit. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is:

1. Defined your style as a `div` style, because you want it to apply to `div`s not `p`s, right? So you should have: `element: 'div'`.
2. Instead of applying the style through styles combo, what will replace paragraphs with divs, use the "Div" button to open the "Create Div Container" dialog and choose your style in the  dialog.

Comment: I made the change suggested in 1. and that didn't have any effect.  But adding the "create div container" dialog button did have the desired effect.  Not as slick as using the drop-down, but it does accomplish what I needed.  Thanks!